# spring.application.name property in application.yaml is fetched as null if profile is active

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have an application.yaml file which specifies the service's name:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: "my-microservice"
```

Now, when I try to fetch it using @Value("spring.application.name") inside my code, I'm able to do that successfully.

But I'm also using a "dev" profile for which I created a separate application-dev.yaml, but I didn't specify the spring.application.name inside this yaml.
Now, when I try to run my code, the @Value annotation gives me a null.
I thought that the fields not specified by application-dev.yaml should be populated using application.yaml, but apparently this is not happening.
Am I supposed to just copy every common field from the default to the dev's application file? Or is there any other way? Any help is appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: You have to fetch value lke this @Value("${spring.application.name}")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out the problem.
It is true that the default application.yaml properties are read by spring for all profiles (unless they have been overwritten by a profile's application file)
But in my case, I was trying to use the @Value annotation on a static field.

```
  @Value("${spring.application.name}")
  private static String applicationName;
```

This caused the null exception in my code. Removing the static context from the field worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to use Spring Expression Language which says we should write it as

```
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;
```

2. For Default value if key is not present in yaml/yml or properties file

```
    @Value("${spring.application.name: defaultValue}") 
    private String appName;
```

3. The last way you can fetch value is using environment object

```
   @Autowired  
   private Environment environment;
       
   String appName = environment.get("spring.application.name");
```